# Enter ipython3 interactive shell when running script with -i option

Tags: python, shell, ipython

If I do `python3 -i myscript.py`, I will enter the default python shell.

My question is: is it possible to enter ipython3 instead of the default shell?

Comment: Are you set up to use `ipython3`?  Did you read its `help`?

Comment: @hpaulj Yes I did